# Django FileField appending temporary path name to media_root path on save

Tags: python, django

I have this custom ModelAdmin that unzips the uploaded file to /tmp and the sets the unzipped file to a FileField in a model doing `mymodel.myfilefield = File(open(path_to_file))`

The thing is that after doing that the new file is copied to `<MEDIA_ROOT>/<upload_to>/tmp/<filename>`

And that's not desired. Why is appending the 'tmp' path?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the to_upload method, I was getting filename and using it as it came.

The fix was to do: `filename = os.path.basename(filename)` and use that